# SQL syntax with more than one row

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I've tried in 1 hour now, trying to find out how I could extract something from the database, in a INNER JOIN with a simple SQL syntax.

It works, nearly and my question is how can i select more than only one row from the table.

My SQL syntax:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, COUNT(posts.post_topic) AS comments
FROM topics
INNER JOIN posts ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic = topics.topic_id
LIMIT 10
```

And of course I don't wanna use the WHERE statement and it doesn't works without WHERE either. Btw. I think it's wrong after ON, but I'm not quite sure there.

Thanks!

Comment: What is you're trying to find out? Is it the number of topics with the value of NULL?  Or is it the number of comments on a post with the value of NULL?  And Aaron looks correct, you definitely don't need the extra clause in the ON.

Comment: Once again, forget about the NULL and WHERE - my bad.

I'm trying to echo the 10 latest topics and then find out how many comments there are on each specified post.

Comment: Show the data - or a sample that shows where you would expect more than one row returned but you only get one row returned.  You should only need a couple of rows in topic and maybe four or five in posts.  Also, don't you need a GROUP BY clause?  Most DBMS (and the SQL standard) would require you to cite that - though in reality, a DBMS can perfectly well infer it and MySQL may actually do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, COUNT(posts.post_topic) AS comments
FROM topics
JOIN posts ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic
GROUP BY topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject
LIMIT 10
```

COUNT is a summary function, but you're not telling the DB how to summarize (i.e. roll up) the data.  The GROUP BY clause states that the data should be rolled up based on topic_id and topic_subject.

If you only select rows where topic_id IS NULL, what do you expect to get?  (I'm assuming it's the primary key.)  I'd expect to get nothing, unless there were some orphaned posts in the posts table.

Comment: It's LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN, but it worked. Thanks! And yes it's the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need the extra `topics.topic_id`?

`SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, COUNT(posts.post_topic) AS comments FROM topics INNER JOIN posts ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic WHERE topic_id = 'NULL' LIMIT 10`

Also, are you sure there is more than one null row in the table?

Comment: I would just select the 10 rows from the database without using where, so the "WHERE topic_id = 'id'" shouldn't be there.

Forget about the null and yes I got more than one row in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The notation:

```
ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic = topics.topic_id
```

might be interpreted as:

```
ON topics.topic_id = (posts.post_topic = topics.topic_id)
```

which could be regarded as "compare topic_id with post_topic and return TRUE or FALSE; then compare the topic_id with TRUE or FALSE and only compare those that match", with (quite possibly) TRUE being converted to 1 and FALSE to 0.

Or the grouping might be:

```
ON (topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic) = topics.topic_id
```

with the same net result.

**Strong recommendation**: remove the superfluous equality condition!

```
ON topics.topic_id = posts.post_topic
```

It confuses the readers, even if it doesn't confuse the DBMS.